# Gnu find: apply -prune to directories which match a pattern in external file

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find, pipe

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to obtain directory patterns for use with -prune from an external file:

```
find . \( -type d -a -exec sh -c "echo \"{}\" | grep -qEx -f patterns.prune" \; \) -prune -o \( <further checks> \)
```

this works but is of course very slow due to the use of a shell/pipe for every previous match. So is there a more elegant way than the above or do i really have to chain the lines of the pattern file as commandline switches for find ?

Thanks.

Comment: I can hardly grok what you've written there but would the exec flag variant `-exec command {} +` from [this man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) help you here?  It appears to me that you're using the `-exec command ;` flag, but I could be way off.

Comment: There are limits to just how complex you can make a find command. I suggest you look at [find2perl](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.3/x2p/find2perl.PL) which has been a standard part of the Perl distribution for a long time. It *would* require knowing or learning  a little Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to pipe to grep at the end of the run, to only invoke it once, i.e. something like:

```
find . <your_other_conditions> | grep -v -f patterns.prune
```

This may not apply to your particular case, since it will now A) find everything under the pruned directories as well (though you can fix that by tweaking patterns.prune) and B) relieve control from *find*, so that you can't use find's builtins (e.g. *-exec*) on the results.